# Access to Windows 10 VM's on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP having switched from AWS.

We need to start a Windows 10 VM that will be used to test our software, as it runs on many different platforms.

When I attempt to install a VM, it only shows Windows Server versions.

Am I looking in the wrong place or is it not possible to install Windows 10 in a VM on GCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [link1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/#windows_client) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/os-details#windows_client) this is possible, but requires you to bring your own image and your own license.